# How to know which files a process is accessing?

Tags: windows, file-access, windows-10

One of the running applications on my windows occasionally uses the internet bandwidth. It might be updating itself but it may access my private files and documents and is sending them over the internet.

How can I know which files a process is accessing or has accessed recently? This way I can make sure that the process is not malicious.

Comment: There are tools showing realtime network and disk access. To some extend Windows Resource manager can help you.

Comment: Process Monitor (procmon.exe) is very definitely your friend. It has to be running while the application accesses the files, though.